# When appending items into an array inside a loop system it is not working (swift)

Tags: xcode, swift

In this code, I am generating values for 2 different arrays. The value inside one array is dependant on the values inside the other array. The way it works is that in the array `next_month_initial`, the value is dependant on the corresponding value in the `water_deficit` array. However, the `water_deficit` array value is dependant on the previous (not corresponding) value in the `next_month_initial` array. Hence why the first value for the `water_deficit array` is calculated independently, as no previous value exists in the `next_month_initial` array. I hope this is clear enough to understand.

The code may be slightly confusing but content wise it is correct, the calculations are correct. There is no error message shown however the program is unable to correctly calculate all of the values in the array. When I print the array, instead of seeing an array with the correct values listed it says "Playground execution failed". I have no idea why this is happening, as i can see it this code should work.

```
var rainfall = [38,94,142,149,236,305,202,82,139,222,178,103]

let max_h2Ostore = 150
let carry_forward = 150

var evap_transpiration: [Int] = []
var water_deficit: [Int] = []
var next_month_initial: [Int] = []


// Generating values for water_deficit array
//The first values is generated differently to the remaining values
water_deficit[0] = rainfall[0] + carry_forward - evap_transpiration[0]

for i in 0...11 {
    var x = i
    if water_deficit[i] <= 0 {
        next_month_initial.append(0)
    } else if water_deficit[i] >= max_h2Ostore {
        next_month_initial.append(max_h2Ostore)
    } else {
        next_month_initial.append(water_deficit[i])
    }; if i != 11 {
        x++
        water_deficit.append(next_month_initial[i] + rainfall[x] - evap_transpiration[x])
    }
}

println(water_deficit)
```

Comment: You haven't initialized the arrays, AFAICT. Oh, and wtf is going on with this line: }; if i != 11 {

Comment: This is a serious case needing a [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)... Your Swift is (sorry) horrible

Comment: @Kametrixom, you're right, this could use a Code Review, but only if the author's code is working.

Comment: I am not surprised, I am very new to programming and swift any ideas on how to improve it?

Comment: @Quill Yes of course

Comment: @NRitH, what does it mean to initialise an array? This is very difficult for me to explain but the reason for the i != 11 is because within the same loop I am trying to calculate a value for position 1 in one array and position 2 in the other array. That is why i have added the var x and needed the x++, to offset the number by 1. the reason for that if statement is to not use rainfall[12] when the array only has 12 values not 13. If that makes any sense.

Comment: @Jack Hayton, initializing an array means populating it with data. Maybe you just didn't include the code that does that. If you try to access an element whose index is greater than or equal to the number of elements in the array, the program will complain. I understand why you're checking the indices from 0 to 11.

Comment: @NRitH, I have included all relevant data, which means that I have not initialised the array. My only other (very limited)  programming knowledge is from python. I believe in python it is possible to create an empty array and append data into it. Is this not the case in swift? If so how do I solve my problem?

Comment: Yes, you can also do that in Swift, with `append()`.

Comment: @NRitH, If so then what do you mean by initialising the array? I have just solved the problem and it had nothing to do with the loops, it was that I had entered in this:
water_deficit[0] = stuff

Instead of water_deficit.append(stuff)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to get your code to "work" you have to

Declare `rainfall` (I guess you have it defined somewhere but it's not in your question) with 12 values:

```
let rainfall = [50, 13, 49, 30, 4, 5, 2, 9, 94, 48, 74, 39]
```

Declare `evap_transpiration` with 12 values:

```
var evap_transpiration: [Int] = [30, 19, 59, 48, 39, 29, 49, 19, 49, 29, 49, 38]
```

Change the line before the loop to (You can't set the 0th element because there are none at that time):

```
water_deficit.append(rainfall[0] + carry_forward - evap_transpiration[0])
```

So your code works. I don't really know if it works correctly as I don't really know what you're trying to do, but at least it doesn't crash. If it does the thing you expect it to do (and it doesn't crash for you!) then I suggest posting your code on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) because this is some of the most horrible Swift code I have ever seen (sorry). I also recommend reading the [The Swift Programming Language](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/swift-programming-language/id881256329?mt=11) book from Apple, it's free and very easy to follow. (If you are posting it on Code Review then please add a good decription of what it does)

Comment: I have changed the code before the loop to your suggestion and this has solved the problem! So this was the issue all along, it had nothing to do with the loops. Im very new to programming so its no surprise my code is as you say horrible, any suggestions/ideas on what i should do to improve it? My code works 100% as it should now though and provides me with the outputs I am looking for. Thanks for the answer.

Both the arrays u mentioned had been declared and filled previously in the program, sorry for not mentioning this in the question.